# Is OFDM equalization performed every 14 symbols?

Tags: fft, ofdm, equalization, channel

The number of symbols and slot in a subframe differs depending on the subcarrier spacing
Is equalization processing performed for each slot? Or per subframe?

Comment: Equalization is done at the resource element level. Every resource element has a channel estimate that is used to do the equalization, ie. zero-forcing or MMSE

Comment: Thanks. For channel estimation,I want use pilot symbol and LS estimation &  interpolation, then equalize received signals.